# XWAS toolset, quality contol for X-chromosome

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I am new in the genetic studies, I will analyze some data specific of the X-chromosome and I will use the Xwas toolset.
I would like to know if there is somone who uses XWAS toolset?  I need help to begin.
Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: Close please, posted at SE Bioinfo where it belongs https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/help-for-using-xwas-toolset